# Will this approach work to track changes of @input variable in child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

there a parent component `parent` and a child component `child`, `parent` component pass a value to its child component.

```
<child childInputValue="value"> </child>
```

in the child component, we want to track when `value` of parent changes and we want to update some other variables of the child accordingly.

I know that ngOnChanges is just for this,

but I'm curious, will this also work

```
@Input()
childInputValue: any;

childInputValue$ = new BehaviourSubject<any>(childInputValue);

childInputValue$.subscribe(() => {
    //childInputValue changes, do something here
})
```

Comment: Here the `BehaviorSubject` is declared with initial value `undefined` since `childInputValue` is `undefined`. The subscription won't emit anything unless it is pushed a new value with `childInputValue$.next('value')`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @MichaelD. That makes perfect sense, I was confused with why do we need ngOnChanges if this works, but now I know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't work. `childInputValue$` will only have initial value and never be updated.

As you mentioned, you can use `ngOnChanges` for tracking.

Also you can use `get/set`:

```
private _childInputValue: any;

@Input()
set childInputValue(value: any) {
    this._childInputValue = value;
    //childInputValue changes, do something here
}

get childInputValue(): any {
    return this._childInputValue;
}
```

or

```
childInputValue$ = new BehaviourSubject<any>(null);

childInputValue$.subscribe(() => {
    //childInputValue changes, do something here
})

@Input()
set childInputValue(value: any) {
    this.childInputValue$.next(value);
}

get childInputValue(): any {
    return this.childInputValue$.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this get/set approach. Thanks for the suggestion and your answer makes everything clear. I'll mark this as accepted.